# How do charged particles accelerate away from an oppositely charged substance? Like in a cathode gun or gridded ion thruster

Tags: electrons, particle-accelerators, ions

Like in the case of a gridded ion thruster, the positive ions are accelerated due to their attraction to a negatively charged gird at the back end of the thruster. Why don't the ions just stay by the grid? How are they ejected out of the back at high speeds? Do the ions simply have a high oscillation amplitude, and are neutralized before they would 'want' to return to the negatively charged grid?

I think I may be misunderstanding a more fundamental piece of the physics? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You asked over on Space Exploration and got a perfectly reasonable answer. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Oh man my understanding must be way off because I felt that it didn't answer my question. Maybe there's a connection I'm missing, because I'm not sure why it's relevant to bring up the fact that the grid is positively charged relative to the spacecraft.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is found by looking at the rate of change of potential, potential gradient, whose magnitude is equal to the electric field which in turn controls the acceleration of charged particles.

Here is a simulation of an electron gun with the cathode (left electrode) at $-480\,\rm kV$ relative to the anode (right electrode).

[image]

Equipotential lines are shown on the right and the energy of the electrons in $\rm eV$ are shown on the left.

Note that the equipotential lines are very close to one another between the two electrodes resulting is a very high accelerating electric field but to the left of the anode the equipotentials are further apart so although there is a decrease in the energy of the electrons travelling in this region it is very much smaller than the increase in kinetic energy between the two electrodes.